Anylogic INtroducing time fluctuations in a dynamic variable
To simulate time variations of economic activity I need to create a fluctuation in time by, as example a sinusoidal function as a positive/negative effect on employement rate.
How can I do this in a dynamic model?
Much thanks from an absolute beginner !
I built a small model that runs linearly.
I want it fluctuates with periodic or random time evolution
I need help for entering a periodic or random time rate (mathematical equation like sin(t)

use a dynamic variable from the system dynamics palette with the forumla sin(time()) or something like that, or use an event from the agent palette that runs cyclically and you can calculate the function there and assign it to a variable=sin(time())
